# Is there a way to pass data (other than through the property bag) between an analyzer and a code fix provider in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, code-analysis, roslyn

with the new RC release, I was excited to see that there now was a property bag to allow raised diagnostics to have additional data, a major use case of which was, in my opinion, to be able to have data computed in the analyzer carried over into a code fixer listening for that particular diagnostic.

I now realize that this property bag only allows to store string values. While this can prove useful, I still find myself having to run the exact same logic in my analyzer and my code fixer since I do not have the ability to just keep this information and pass it on. I am of course talking about more complex types, such as syntax nodes and symbols.

For example, I created an analyzer that enforced the presence of particular set of `using` directives in every file. The analyzer computes which directives are missing and raises a diagnostic that notifies the user and textually indicates the missing directives. The code fix provider would be pretty straight forward if I already had the `SyntaxNode`s I have to implement (which I already have in my analyzer), but I now have to re-run much of the same logic in my code fixer (which is why I ended up putting a lot of code present in my analyzer in public static helper methods)

Now, this example lost some of its relevance since the introduction of the property bag, but I still think it is a valid use case. I am especially concerned that the only link between the analyzer and the code fixer in the location of the reported diagnostic. In my case, I can have multiple `DiagnosticDescriptor` instances that could all represent different potential problems stemming from a particular "Rule", as defined by a `Diagnostic` and its `Id` (I have no idea if that is a good practice in the realm of Roslyn code analysis, but is seemed like an acceptable way to operate).

Bottom line is: for the same diagnostic Id, I could potentially have the diagnostic raised at different locations (i.e. on completely different syntax elements) depending on the case. I therefore lose the "certainty" of having the provided location be on a definitive and/or relevant syntax element, and the subsequent logic to fix the diagnostic goes out the window.

So, is there any way to pass data from the analyzer to a related code fix provider ? I also thought about downcasting an instance of a custom type that derives from `Diagnostic`, but it seemed like a code smell to me and, furthermore, `Diagnostic` is full of abstract members that I would need to re-implement for the sole purpose of adding one property, and `SimpleCodeFix` is sealed (argggghhhh)

Comment: Why do you think it's bad to recompute the data for the fix? In general you should do the absolute minimum work you can in the diagnostic, since that happens over the whole program, and defer as much work as possible into the fix, since that happens only occasionally, and only when the user requests it.

Comment: I agree with the fact that the minimum amount of work should be done in the analyzer, but if the processing that is required for a particular analyzer to provide an accurate analysis and report a particular problem through a diagnostic already gives me the information that I need, should I not have a way to provide this (in my opinion, potentially highly relevant) information to the code fixer ? 

Furthermore, I would stop short of calling it *bad* to recompute the same things twice, but it's certainly something I'd rather avoid if I had the chance, don't you agree ?

Comment: One of the reasons why the API *doesn't* provide a way to store data other strings in the diagnostic is that we are considering potential future uses of analyzers where they may not run in the same process as the fix, and the diagnostic would need to be serialized.

Comment: I did not know that you were considering having this kind on model in the future. That being said, you seem to have misunderstood my intention in the original question: I had not intention of intentionnaly offloading work to the analyzer. I was just saying that some information is bound to be obtained when trying to find out *if* and *where* a diagnostic should be raised. Since this information is relevant to the diagnostic, it goes to say that it will probably be relevant for the code fixer.

Comment: Another example to underline my point would be to validate that a chain invocation such as X.Foo(...).Bar (...).DoSomething("Y") must have the parameter that is passed to DoSomething be a string litteral which value's represent the name of the variable that is the root of the member acces chain (in that instance, "X" != "Y", so the analyzer would flag a diagnostic). To even detect that a diagnostic should be reported, I have to handle some logic, such as having 'this.X' (in which case only X should be targeted for equality) or only targeting 'DoSomething' methods, and so on...

Comment: In this previous example, I'm doing the bare minimum work to *detect* the diagnostic (i.e. if there is a mismatch between the leftmost member in the chain and the given argument), but, as far as I understand, if I want to have 2 different code fixers (let's say one that corrects the name of the leftmost member or another that instead corrects the textual value of the argument), I have no way of getting the data that is already available from the diagnostic analysis process into the code fixer. I have to duplicate my logic, or at the very least re-execute it in order to get what I want.

Comment: Sorry for the wall of text, but I hope this clears up my intention and potential need for a way to pass data from analyzer to fixer. From your very valid clarification about the potential future serialization of diagnostics, I understand better why a more direct and/or flexible approach has not been adopted. That being said, how would you recommend I tackle these kind of issues ? Or is re-running the same logic twice to get the expected results considered as the accepted way of doing things ? In which case, how to make it as concise as possible ? Am I just missing something obvious ?

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue. I have an analyzer that checks if the argument passed to an `ArgumentException` is a parameter to the method but as a string. This needs to be done in the analyzer and now I'll have to do it again in the code fix because I can't just tell the fix "hey, the parameter you need to change is <X>". I'm not too familiar with serialization or different process so I can't say much about that, but what prevents you from serializing the passed through data?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel That's pretty much what I ended up doing. I posted my solution as an answer, feel free to look at it and tell me what your thoughts are.

Comment: Same goes for you @KevinPilch-Bisson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Kevin mentioned that there was no real way to accomplish what I was trying to do natively because the diagnostics are expected to be serializable, it got me thinking that I could somewhat emulate what I wanted through serialization. I am
posting the solution I came up with to solve the issue. Feel free to criticize and/or underline some potential issues.

> SyntaxElementContainer

```
public class SyntaxElementContainer<TKey> : Dictionary<string, string>
{
    private const string Separator = "...";
    private static readonly string DeserializationPattern = GetFormattedRange(@"(\d+)", @"(\d+)");

    private static string GetFormattedRange(string start, string end)
    {
        return $"{start}{Separator}{end}";
    }

    public SyntaxElementContainer()
    {
    }

    public SyntaxElementContainer(ImmutableDictionary<string, string> propertyBag)
        : base(propertyBag)
    {
    }

    public void Add(TKey nodeKey, SyntaxNode node)
    {
        Add(nodeKey.ToString(), SerializeSpan(node?.Span));
    }

    public void Add(TKey tokenKey, SyntaxToken token)
    {
        Add(tokenKey.ToString(), SerializeSpan(token.Span));
    }

    public void Add(TKey triviaKey, SyntaxTrivia trivia)
    {
        Add(triviaKey.ToString(), SerializeSpan(trivia.Span));
    }


    public TextSpan GetTextSpanFromKey(string syntaxElementKey)
    {
        var spanAsText = this[syntaxElementKey];
        return DeSerializeSpan(spanAsText);
    }

    public int GetTextSpanStartFromKey(string syntaxElementKey)
    {
        var span = GetTextSpanFromKey(syntaxElementKey);
        return span.Start;
    }

    private string SerializeSpan(TextSpan? span)
    {
        var actualSpan = span == null || span.Value.IsEmpty ? default(TextSpan) : span.Value; 
        return GetFormattedRange(actualSpan.Start.ToString(), actualSpan.End.ToString());
    }

    private TextSpan DeSerializeSpan(string spanAsText)
    {
        var match = Regex.Match(spanAsText, DeserializationPattern);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            var spanStartAsText = match.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value;
            var spanEndAsText = match.Groups[2].Captures[0].Value;

            return TextSpan.FromBounds(int.Parse(spanStartAsText), int.Parse(spanEndAsText));
        }

        return new TextSpan();
    }   
}
```

> PropertyBagSyntaxInterpreter

```
public class PropertyBagSyntaxInterpreter<TKey>
{
    private readonly SyntaxNode _root;

    public SyntaxElementContainer<TKey> Container { get; }

    protected PropertyBagSyntaxInterpreter(ImmutableDictionary<string, string> propertyBag, SyntaxNode root)
    {
        _root = root;
        Container = new SyntaxElementContainer<TKey>(propertyBag);
    }

    public PropertyBagSyntaxInterpreter(Diagnostic diagnostic, SyntaxNode root)
        : this(diagnostic.Properties, root)
    {
    }

    public SyntaxNode GetNode(TKey nodeKey)
    {
        return _root.FindNode(Container.GetTextSpanFromKey(nodeKey.ToString()));
    }

    public TSyntaxType GetNodeAs<TSyntaxType>(TKey nodeKey) where TSyntaxType : SyntaxNode
    {
        return _root.FindNode(Container.GetTextSpanFromKey(nodeKey.ToString())) as TSyntaxType;
    }


    public SyntaxToken GetToken(TKey tokenKey)
    {

        return _root.FindToken(Container.GetTextSpanStartFromKey(tokenKey.ToString()));
    }

    public SyntaxTrivia GetTrivia(TKey triviaKey)
    {
        return _root.FindTrivia(Container.GetTextSpanStartFromKey(triviaKey.ToString()));
    }
}
```

> Use case (simplified for shortness' sake)

```
// In the analyzer
MethodDeclarationSyntax someMethodSyntax = ...
var container = new SyntaxElementContainer<string>
{
    {"TargetMethodKey", someMethodSyntax}
};

// In the code fixer
var bagInterpreter = new PropertyBagSyntaxInterpreter<string>(diagnostic, root);
var myMethod = bagInterpreter.GetNodeAs<MethodDeclarationSyntax>("TargetMethodKey");
```

Comment: I would add somewhere that in order to have a diagnostic with a property bag, you need to call the overload that takes one.